# Update object in array from another object in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

In my code I have two arrays, first one contains multiple objects. While the second one is to store serialized form data (mapped to JSON). So both arrays are having identical keys.

What I want to achieve is to update the values of an object in the original array based on the values of an object in new array dynamically, by ID in the object.

Found some examples online but hard to get them to work. Because most of them are showing either one level of objects but I'm working on complex nested objects in the array.

```
var products = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Product1',
        Attributes: {
            Storage: 'Normal',
            Size: 'Small'
        }
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Product2',
        Attributes: {
            Storage: 'Normal',
            Size: 'Small'
        }
    }
];

var newData = [
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'French Fries'
    },
    {
        Id: 1,
        Attributes: {
            Size: 'Medium'
        }
    }
];
```

The expected outcome is the `products` array now updated with the values from the second array.

```
Output:
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Product1',
        Attributes: {
            Storage: 'Normal',
            Size: 'Medium'
        }
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'French Fries',
        Attributes: {
            Storage: 'Normal',
            Size: 'Small'
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Why `size` in first object is not changed. It should have changed to `medium` because in `newData` object with id `1` have size `medium`

Comment: @MaheerAli oh yes you are right. Corrected it now. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: What's the criteria for `2` to have only "Size: Small" and not "Storage: Normal" as well?... While `1` updates its attributes.

Comment: @briosheje Sorry it was purely mistake. The output for `2` should have `"Storage: Normal"` as well. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Okay. Are `Id` unique? can you reference items by that key for looking up?

Comment: @briosheje Yeap yeap `Id` is unique. And yes that's what I want to achieve. Reference items by `Id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the update items and iterate `products`.

If an item is found for an update, take a recursive approach and iterate the entries and check if the value is an object, then iterate the nested properties.

If no nested object found update the property.

This works for arrays as well.

```js
function update(target, source) {
    Object.entries(source).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
            update(target[key] = target[key] || (Array.isArray(value) ? [] : {}), value);
        } else if (target[key] !== value) {
            target[key] = value;
        }
    });
}

var products = [{ Id: 1, Name: 'Product1', Attributes: { Storage: 'Normal', Size: 'Small' } }, { Id: 2, Name: 'Product2', Attributes: { Storage: 'Normal', Size: 'Small' } }],
    newData = [{ Id: 2, Name: 'French Fries' }, { Id: 1, Attributes: { Size: 'Medium' } }],
    map = new Map(newData.map(o => [o.Id, o]));

products.forEach(o => map.has(o.Id) && update(o, map.get(o.Id)));

console.log(products);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it seems like when updating nested properties, it's adding the updated properties to the root key instead of its own parent key. And the parent key that contains the actual key remains unchanged.

Comment: maybe your data is not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which combine nested objects. And then use `map()` and `find()` to create combined array of objects.

```js
var products = [
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: 'Product1',
        Attributes: {
            Storage: 'Normal',
            Size: 'Small'
        }
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Product2',
        Attributes: {
            Storage: 'Normal',
            Size: 'Small'
        }
    }
];

var newData = [
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'French Fries'
    },
    {
        Id: 1,
        Attributes: {
            Size: 'Medium'
        }
    }
];

const haveNested = obj => Object.values(obj).some(x => typeof x === "object");

function combine(obj1,obj2){

  if(!haveNested(obj1)) return ({...obj1,...obj2})
  let res = obj1
  for(let key in obj1){
    if(typeof obj1[key] === "object"){
      res[key] = combine(obj1[key],obj2[key]);
    }
    else if(obj2[key]) res[key] = obj2[key]
  }
  return res;
}

const result = products.map(x => {
  let temp = newData.find(a => a.Id === x.Id);
  return temp ? combine(x,temp) : x;
})

console.log(result)
```